# Removing video from embed youtube video

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am trying to make a website for educational purposes, and i am trying to play music there, do you know if theres any way to "share" a youtube video but removing all the video features making only remain something like this.

![Youtube Videoless]http://blazrobar.com/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Youtube-player-preview.jpg

For those who cannt see the image the features would be play, go back, go forward, the slide bar showing the duration, and finally quality selection (All the others are referent to videos(Except that one that could forward you to the youtube video)

Thanks for reading! I hope i can learn with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [navarr.me/ytaudio](http://navarr.me/ytaudio/)

I'd suggest you check `Allow YouTube to collect cookies` otherwise it usually doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, very thanks this is exactly it!
But do you know if there any automatic way to do it? 
I mean i insert the link video and auto converts to this without going to the website?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to go to the website each time. If you inspect the `Embeddable Code` provaded by `navarr.me/ytaudio` you will see that the only thing you have to do is to change the video-id in the `data="..."` property. `ytaudio` doesn't do wonders, it just embeds a normal youtube player with height="25" so that you don't see the video but it still plays.

Comment: Btw the correct way of saying "Thank you" in Stackoverflow is to accept my answer - the tick on left of the answer.

Comment: Pardon me for i have not see it, i tried to do +1 but said i hadnt enough rep. Didnt i could do that soo there you go mate! Thanks for helpibg i got it working fine! :)